# jqGrid: Form view on double clicking a treeview grid

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

I am new to JqGrid. I would like to get a form view of the row(part of the treeview grid) that I have double clicked on. And I am not using a navigation bar. I tried the following and it did not work.

```
ondblClickRow: function(rowid) {
$("#list2").GridToForm(rowid, "#container");
}
```

Where am I go wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the code

```
ondblClickRow: function(rowid) {
    $("#list2").jqGrid('viewGridRow', rowid, {closeOnEscape:true} );
}
```

will do what you want.